# How we can send corresponding email verification link admin, vendor and user auth in laravel,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-authorization

How we can send corresponding email verification link admin, vendor and user auth in laravel,
as 
admin: admin.verification.email (http://139.59.75.219/welwel/public/admin/email/verify/1?expires=1552402747&signature=b3768d97b4d98bb226171e880a95802e68540aae9f5f21f78a9782fce895c960)

vendor: vendor.verification.email (http://139.59.75.219/welwel/public/vendor/email/verify/1?expires=1552402747&signature=b3768d97b4d98bb226171e880a95802e68540aae9f5f21f78a9782fce895c960)

user already have verification.email (http://139.59.75.219/welwel/public/email/verify/1?expires=1552402747&signature=b3768d97b4d98bb226171e880a95802e68540aae9f5f21f78a9782fce895c960)

Even I have use:
**Vendor\Auth\VerificationController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Vendor\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class VerificationController extends Controller{
use VerifiesEmails;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('vendor');
    $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
    $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
}
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->route('id') != $request->user('vendor')->getKey()) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($request->user('vendor')->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user('vendor')));
    }

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
public function resend(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->user('vendor')->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    $request->user('vendor')->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('resent', true);
}
}
```

middleware: **VendorEnsureEmailIsVerified.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
class VendorEnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->user('vendor') ||
            ($request->user('vendor') instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
            ! $request->user('vendor')->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                    : Redirect::route('vendor.verification.notice');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

other thing working fine, only link generating only for user, not seoreate for admin, vendor and user